# Repeated inputs of Linear Interpolation

Tags: python

I'd like to modify this code so that it repeatedly asks for different values for x, and outputs the corresponding values for y.

```
x1 = input("x1 = ")
x2 = input("x2 = ")
y1 = input("y1 = ")
y2 = input("y2 = ")

x = input("x = ")

y = y1 * ((x-x2)/(x1-x2)) + y2 * ((x-x1)/(x2-x1))
print y
```

I'm aware I need to create an infinite loop around the `x` input and the function itself where you can then create a break by typing a word, e.g. `'Stop'`, but can't seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I make this stop when someone types `stop`"? It's not clear to us what you need help with or how your code is "wrong".

Comment: Hey Relic, check out this link: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop
It has a great example of using a stop word to break out of an infinite loop. Don't be put off by @jonrsharpe, Stack Overflow is mainly for answering specific technical questions, not design or `how-to` questions.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I guess I could have been more specific with my question and perhaps this wasn't the right place to ask. I can create a loop where it prompts the user for an infinite input until a "key word" is used to break it, but am unsure how to fit the loop into my existing code to get repeated values of y out until you break it. Will continue to read more!

Comment: @Relic, you might also check the posting guidelines in "the tour" mentioned in your intro materials.  Specifically, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here: post an honest attempt at the problem, show us the output you got, and describe what you wanted in those specific terms.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for the information, it seems to me I've complied with the rules and without pasting endless amounts of incorrect code or "attempts" the majority is above. I didn't realize asking such a mundane question would cause such a stir. Interesting forum you have here...

Comment: Agreed.  :-)  I provided the link so you could see how/why the responders had expectations different from what you supplied.  Supplying one or two attempts would have avoided triggering some of those "red flags".

Answer (score 0):

From the `print y` line it looks like you're using Python 2.7 or earlier, so `input("x = ")` will more than likely respond to you
entering `stop` with the exception `NameError: name 'stop' is not defined`.  I suggest using `raw_input`, which returns the user's input
as a string; you can check if the string is equal to the string
`"stop"` before attempting to turn it into a float.

Forcing the inputs to be floats also means you don't have to worry about integer division confusing things (Google for `from __future__ import division` for more).

Here's an example:

```
x1 = float(raw_input("x1 = "))
x2 = float(raw_input("x2 = "))
y1 = float(raw_input("y1 = "))
y2 = float(raw_input("y2 = "))

print 'enter "stop" to end'

while True:
    rawx = raw_input("x = ")
    if 'stop' == rawx:
        print "stopping..."
        break

    x = float(rawx)

    y = y1 * ((x-x2)/(x1-x2)) + y2 * ((x-x1)/(x2-x1))
    print y
```

Run with Python 2.7 on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, I get this:

```
$ python q33264238.py
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
y1 = -1
y2 = 1
enter "stop" to end
x = 1
-1.0
x = 2
1.0
x = 1.5
0.0
x = stop
stopping...
```